# Get full url regex

Tags: php, regex

I have this regex which is working correctly for urls but when i use a url containing @ it doesnot show anything after @. How can i edit the regex to show full url

```
    <?php

$regex = "/(https?\:\/\/|\s)[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})(\/+[a-z0-9_.\:\;-]*)*(\?[\&\%\|\+a-z0-9_=,\.\:\;-]*)?([\&\%\|\+&a-z0-9_=,\:\;\.-]*)([\!\#\/\&\%\|\+a-z0-9_=,\:\;\.-]*)}*/i";


$url = "http://www.flickr.com/photos/16506140@N05/8376411748/in/photostream/";

preg_match_all($regex, $url, $matches);

echo'<pre>';
print_r($matches);
echo '<pre>';

?>
```

DEMO http://codepad.viper-7.com/oVHcdN

Comment: Well if you wrote it then you should know that you must just add some `@` somewhere ... For sake of simplicity, I may use `~https?://\S+~i`

Comment: @HamZa copied it from somewhere. I have a very lil knowlege of regex. can u show me regex with added @ & `~https?;//\S+~i`

Comment: try with this    $regex = "/(https?\:\/\/|\s)[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})(\/+[a-z0-9_.\:\;-]*)*(\?[\&\%\|\+a-z0-9_=,\.\:\;-]*)?([\&\%\|\+&a-z0-9_=,\:\;\.-@]*)([\!\#\/\&\%\|\+a-z0-9_=,\:\;\.-]*)}*/i";

Comment: @user2894116 anubhava just found a duplicate, you may use it.

Comment: @Nomanaliabbasi Quote your code with backticks `\``.

Comment: @Nomanaliabbasi Not working http://codepad.viper-7.com/Z6oQNu

Comment: Wonder about the discussion here.. Use `parse_url()`, that's all

Comment: `$regex = "/(https?\:\/\/|\s)[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})(\/+[a-z0-9_.\:\;-]*)*(\?[\&\%\|\+a-z0-9_=,\.\:\;-]*)?([\&\%\|\+&a-z0-9_=,\:\;\.-@]*)([\!\#\/\&\%\|\+a-z0-9_=,\:\;\.-]*)}*/i";`

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => http://www.flickr.com/photos/16506140@N05/8376411748/in/photostream/
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => http://
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => .flickr
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => .com
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => /16506140
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => @N05/8376411748/in/photostream/
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
        )

)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to access several parts of an url you are highly encouraged to use the function [`parse_url()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) instead of a custom regex solution:

```
$url = "http://www.flickr.com/photos/16506140@N05/8376411748/in/photostream/";
var_dump(parse_url($url));
```

Output:

```
array(3) {
  ["scheme"]=>
  string(4) "http"
  ["host"]=>
  string(14) "www.flickr.com"
  ["path"]=>
  string(47) "/photos/16506140@N05/8376411748/in/photostream/"
}
```

Comment: Can i use it instead of regex ?

Comment: yes, it is meant as a replacement for your regex solution           .